# Zero set of finitely many polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

[image: Picture of the Proof]

Somebody asked a question earlier regarding this proof but I'm confused about a different part. I understand everything but the line "As the zero set of finitely many polynomials, $R$ is a closed subset of $S \times S$".

Can somebody help explain to me what this statement means? What does it mean to be the zero set of finitely many polynomials? What polynomials is $R$ the zero set of? Do the polynomials mentioned come from the determinants of the minors? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Given polynomials $f_1(x,y),\dots,f_n(x,y)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb R$, the zero set of the polynomials in $S \times S$ is the set of all $(a,b) \in S \times S$ such that $f_i(a,b)=0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. In this case, the polynomials in question do indeed come from the determinant minors discussed.

Comment: Does the statement that the set is closed follow from the intersections of the $f_i ^{-1}(0)$ being closed? Is this what makes the finiteness necessary?

Comment: Exactly. Since $\{0\}$ is closed and all $f_i$'s are continuous, each $f_i^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed and so is their intersection.

Comment: @vociferous_rutabaga Can we alternatively prove using fundamental theorem of algebra? Please see my question: [Are zero sets of polynomial equations closed because of the fundamental theorem of algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012580/are-zero-sets-of-polynomial-equations-closed-because-of-the-fundamental-theorem).